# Space and Time Equality and information transfer between particles existing at different time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

Since space and time are the same is it that whatever happens at different positions in space should take place at different time? If what I think is correct consider an electric dipole, the charges are at different positions in space then, can there be electrostatic attraction between the charges even if they are individually present in different time?

To make it more clear what I’m thinking about consider the following. I have a body with charge Q1 at time t1 and then I neutralized it. At another instant of time t2 I have another body with charge Q2. Can there be electrostatic forces of attraction between the charges Q1 which was present at time t1 and Q2 which is present at time t2(remember that at time t2 there is no charge Q1 as I had neutralized the first body) i.e can there be EM force between charges that don’t exist at the same time like there can be entanglement between particles which do not exist at the same time as given in this article(http://news.sciencemag.org/sciencenow/2013/05/physicists-create-quantum-link-b.html)?

Comment: I'll give you a hint: Classical Electromagnetism is governed by Maxwell's equations; would you try that here? .

Comment: OP wrote (v2): _I have a body with charge $Q_1$ at time $t_1$ and then I neutralized it._ Presumably with a charge $-Q_1$ coming in from spatial infinity. Please include and indicate the whereabouts of all parts of the physical system to form a consistent picture.

Answer (score 1):

> Since space and time are the same [...]

Relativity doesn't say that space and time are the same. It says that they are closely related in the sense that they are treated symmetrically by the laws of physics, and they mix together when you switch frames of reference. (The mixing is also present in Galilean relativity.)

> [...] is it that whatever happens at different positions in space should take place at different time?

No, because space and time are not the same.